# How to enable postgresql-anonymizer for cloudsql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, anonymize

Google Cloud notes that the [postgresql_anonymizer extension can be loaded by switching the cloudsql.enable-on flag to on](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgresql_anonymizer). However, when running anon commands (e.g trying to initialize the extension with `SELECT anon.init();`) on the database I'm told this:

`ERROR:  schema "anon" does not exist`

Is there any additional configuration that needs to occur?